# Google maps with android only shows white screen

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm making an app that uses google maps. However, it just shows a white screen. I've googled, and it seems like the problem is the key. However, on two other computers with other phones running the exact same app, it works without problems. So I do not really see how the key could be the problem. It seems more like a problem with my computer or phone. Does anyone know what may cause this?

Comment: Are Google Play services enabled on the phone?

Comment: Yes. At least when I go to apps and choose google play services, it shows up and gives me the possibility to disable it (thus making me believe that it is currently enabled). I can also use all the google play service apps.

Comment: are you using debug key for google maps ? or release key ?

Comment: You probably didn't add the SHA-1 of your debug certificate. Follow this steps for that particular computer: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem!
However, I am wondering. How come I need a different key on this computer than on another one?